# For a time series, does finite variance imply finite autocovariance?

Tags: time-series, variance, covariance

If variance is finite at all times, does this imply that all pairwise autocovariances are also finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any times $s$ and $t$, the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) gives us
$$
|\text{Cov}(X_s,X_t)|^2 \leq \text{Var}(X_s)\text{Var}(X_t) < \infty.
$$

If you're worried about the means being possibly infinite/undefined, the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91512/) might be helpful.